# What's the time complexity of below program?

Tags: java, big-o

What's the time complexity of this program? We calculate time complexity based on arbitrarily large input. In this example, the input string can be really huge but if it will not have spaces then it's just O(n). In case if the string has spaces it's going to be O(n * numberOfWords), can I consider this as O(n^2) time complexity? Thank you in advance!

```
    public static String revEachWord(String str) {
        String reversed = "";
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        
        for(String word : words) {
            String reversedWord = "";
            for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reversedWord += word.charAt(i);
            }

            reversed += reversedWord + " ";
        }
        
        return reversed.trim();
    }
```

Comment: The fact that you're using `String` concatenation means that it will be _much, much_ higher. A `StringBuilder` is necessary here. (This is a language-specific detail but an important one.)

Comment: The question was on time complexity, not for space complexity. In my understanding theoretically, using String(takes more space) should not effect Big O time complexity.

Comment: Every single time you use `+=` you're creating at least 2 new objects and copies. That takes time.

Comment: As some of the comments and other answers have suggested, determining the complexity of an algorithm written in a language like Java can be deceptively difficult. The language and it's standard libraries offer so many features, and it becomes a double edged sword: while it lets us collapse some rather complex operations into a single statement in our own code, it can also hide the true cost of that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aleksey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5723817/aleksey-samoylov) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62506985/2093695) that it's `O(numberOfWords * averageWordLength)`. This is correct (if we ignore `+=` for a moment), but a more general answer would be in terms of the length of the input, `n`. Since `n = numberOfWords * averageWordLength`, we can say that it's `O(n)`, or linear.

But that's not quite right. As [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) pointed out in a comment, since you're using `+=` to build your string, it would take much longer: `O(n)` for each copy and `numberOfWords` total copies, for `O(n * numberOfWords)` total, or `O(n^2)` in the worst case. (It might be even worse than that, actually; I haven't factored in the `+=` in the nested loop.) Yikes. Better start using `StringBuilder` to get that nice `O(n)` running time.

Answer (score -2):

O(numberOfWords * averageWordLength)